# Cordova run android --- not deploying to my android phone connected but opening up emulator instead

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

Just created the basic cordova app (the Hello World app it generates), and 
while

```
cordova emulate android
```

works fine on the emulator,

```
cordova run android
```

also fires up the emulator. My Samsung S5 is connected to the PC and USB debugging mode is enabled (after taping the build in settings 7 times, etc. http://www.valuewalk.com/2014/04/samsung-galaxy-s5-enable-usb-debugging-mode/ )

How to deploy it to my device directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb install path/to/local/apk

Or try with -s to install it on your phone's sd card. Apk path can be found in the build process's log, at the console.

Close the emulators first.